# c++ make_pair no matching function found

Tags: c++, std-pair

I have the following code

```
        #include <utility>

        using namespace std;

        int a = ...//gets calculated somehow
        int b = ...//same here 
        char container[a][b];
        ...
        std::pair<int, char**> p = make_pair(1, container);
```

The last line gives me

```
main.cpp:10:58: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(int, char [a][b])'
         std::pair<int, char**> p = make_pair(1, container);
                                                          ^
main.cpp:10:58: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/utility:70:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
     make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_pair.h:276:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:58: note:   variable-sized array type 'char (&)[a][b]' is not a valid template argument
         std::pair<int, char**> p = make_pair(1, container);
                                                          ^
main.cpp:10:32: warning: unused variable 'p' [-Wunused-variable]
         std::pair<int, char**> p = make_pair(1, container);
```

Comment: shouldnt that be `std::make_pair` ?

Comment: Say it with me: An array is not a pointer.

Comment: Oh please don't use VLAs.. use a vector and stop using pointer/arrays mixtures and you'll have no problems

Comment: @aschepler: That would explain it if the error was about converting a pair from one type to another.

Comment: But shouldn't the error then be about the wrong convertion? How else am I supposed to set the types?

Comment: That conversion error will come up as soon as there's actually a conversion going on. There's no from type because there's no `make_pair` with the from type as its return type. Fix that error and then the other will appear.

Comment: @chris: I found the full error message.  The key part is this: `variable-sized array type 'char (&)[a][b]' is not a valid template argument`

Comment: @MooingDuck, Guess I shouldn't have assumed it was valid. I don't use VLAs.

Comment: @wasp256 - That map with `char**` as a value type only works if the type you're assigning is a `char**`.  So it's up to you as to how to address this -- either you assign a `char**`, or you change the type to use a container type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold. Firstly, the dimensions of a statically-allocated array must be compile-time constants. Variable-length arrays (VLAs) are non-standard but are supported by certain compilers as extensions. I would stay away from these though as to maintain the standard conformance and portability of the program.

Making `a` and `b` `const` should suffice:

```c++
int const a = 5;
int const b = 10;
char container[a][b];
```

Next, the type of the `p` does not match the type returned from `make_pair(1, container)`. Internally, `make_pair` "decays" the deduced type of the arguments (applies array-to-pointer conversion in this case). The decayed type of second argument `container` does not turn into `char**` but rather `char (*)[3]` - a pointer to the first element which is itself an array.

So changing that line to this should work:

```c++
std::pair<int, char (*)[3]> p = std::make_pair(1, container);
```

You also might want to use `auto` so that type deduction alleviates the confusion:

```c++
auto p = std::make_pair(1, container);
```

And consider using `std::vector<std::string>` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: Actually, in this case the VLAs cause the `make_pair` failure too - it's not a conversion failure.